# Recommended Hooks to Liquibase, to Audit executed SQL into a db table

Tags: liquibase

to make liquibase troubleshooting during development phase easier, I'd like to make a hook to liquibase when running goal liquibase:update  to have every successful executed SQL be inserted to a table by liquibase.  I can't find any information on how to do this.   Going through the source code, I can make a guess overriding class method  JdbcExecutor.execute  seems to be the one possibility to achieve this.  But this is not a clean solution, as I use maven to run liquibase:update goal.

Answer (score 0):

Writing your own extensions would be one way to do it, but it seems to me that just using --logLevel=debug and collecting the SQL from there might be a better way to accomplish what you want. That won't put it in a database, but you would have the information you need. You can also run the `updateSQL` command before running the `update` command to get the SQL that would be generated.

Comment: thanks I'll take a look at extensions.   In my pom.xml I already have <liquibase.logging>DEBUG</liquibase.logging>.      when there is sql error, it's hard to see, which SQL caused the issue.  I use straight sql in liquibase changesets, in my xml files a changeset can have 1 or more sql like this --> <sqlfile path="./filename.sql" stripComments="true" splitStatements="true" encoding="utf8" endDelimiter="\n/" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>